# Issue with scanning in words from a file (in C)

Tags: c, file-io

I am currently attempting to write a function which scans words in from a dictionary file. It works perfectly in the debugger but when I compile and run it normally, it crashes after five words scanned. Here is my code:

```
char** readDictionary(FILE *ifp, int size){
    int i;
    char** dictionary;
    char buffer[21];

    dictionary = malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);
    if(dictionary == NULL){
        printf("dictionary allocation ERROR");
        return NULL;
    }

    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer);
        printf("%s\n", buffer); //debugging statement
        dictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));
        strcpy(dictionary[i], buffer);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

In the debugger, all words are scanned in properly. When I run without the debugger, I crash after the fifth word.

here is a list of my first few words (again, it crashes after aardvarks):
aahing
aahs
aals
aardvark
aardvarks
aardwolf
aardwolves

I am not sure why this could be happening. Please help.

Comment: Check `fscanf()` return value. Don't use `sizeof(char)` it's simply `1` and will always be, also you need the terminating *null* byte.

Comment: the reason such work in a debugger is that the debug version of the program often has padded memory blocks so forgetting \0 may seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allocating space for the terminating *null* byte. Change

```
dictionary[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer));
strcpy(dictionary[i], buffer);
```

to

```
size_t length = strlen(buffer);
dictionary[i] = malloc(length + 1);
if (dictionary[i] != NULL)
    memcpy(dictionary[i], buffer, length + 1);
```

Or even better

```
dictionary[i] = strdup(buffer);
```

Also, check that `fscanf()` didn't faile if it didn't it will return `1` in your case.

Comment: strdup worked perfectly! thank you. Just to make sure, is it part of the standard C library?

Comment: @remington howell  No., `strdup()` in not in the C standard library. It is common though.

Comment: @remingtonhowell But there are equivalents in most [tag:c] libraries.

Comment: @remington howell Sample : `char *strdup(const char *s) {
  if (s == NULL) return NULL;
  size_t siz = strlen(s) + 1;
  char *y = malloc(siz);
  if (y != NULL) {
    memcpy(y, s, siz);
  }
  return y;
}`